# OpenUI5: Add margins on both sides to ToolPage

Tags: css, sapui5, margin

I am using OpenUI5 ToolPage for my App. In all the demos, this `ToolPage` takes 100% of the available width but I would like to set left and right margins using media queries.

```
<mvc:View
    height="100%"
    controllerName="internal_app.controller.App"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:tnt="sap.tnt">

<tnt:ToolPage id="app" class="internalAppToolPage">
    <tnt:header>
        <tnt:ToolHeader>
######
```

My view looks like this. I added class `internalAppToolPage` to the `ToolPage` and set the CSS

```
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
    .internalAppToolPage {
        width: 1280px !important;
        margin-left: 50%;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    }
}
```

but this causes the complete Page to be shifted to the right. What am I doing wrong. Sorry if this too dump, but I just can't see my error.

Comment: Avoid width: 1280px !important; Because your min-width is also same size. Btw your question is not very clear show some screen or requirement. also margin-left:50% will not give you both side margin You have to provide margin:0 30%; something like this

Answer (score 0):

If you are concern about the margin on both side only then no need to use the media queries. As UI5 `sap.m` library provide a responsive layout.

Just you need to use the *standard UI5 classes* which will help you achieve your requirement.

You can go through [Standard Margins](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.core.StandardMargins) which provides different *margins* class. It also provide responsive class.

You can also refer to [Standard Padding](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.core.ContainerPadding) as per your requirement.